# Wireless dongle DWA-131 not working

Tags: wireless

I have purchased a dlink dwa-131 wireless usb dongle. But I am unable to bring it up. I had read in the list of hardware supported that this is plug and play on Ubuntu.

I saw the [wireless trouble shooting procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WirelessTroubleshootingProcedure) and got the logs. I Have pasted below the log. also i see dlink listed in lsusb. But it is not seen in below log. The on board Intel pro chip-set isn't working. Hence I brought this dongle.

I couldn't paste the log as there was an error that I need 10 reputation to post more than 2 links. Hence I have deleted the links in the log.

```
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package hwinfo
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1f:3c:a0:c6:69
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:42 memory:f0000000-f0000fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller Mobile
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 8
       bus info: pci@0000:02:08.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:1e:ec:a1:d5:f0
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=half latency=64 link=no maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:20 memory:f0101000-f0101fff ioport:2000(size=64)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
02:08.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller Mobile [8086:1068] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:30d5]
    Kernel driver in use: e100
10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:135b]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2001:330d D-Link Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         disconnected    disabled        disabled   enabled         disabled
```

## H/W path        Device      Class       Description

```
                            system      HP 520 Notebook PC (FH562AA#UUF)
/0                          bus         30D5
/0/0                        memory      128KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo CPU      T2700  @ 2.33GHz
/0/4/5                      memory      64KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                      memory      2MiB L2 cache
/0/4/0.1                    processor   Logical CPU
/0/4/0.2                    processor   Logical CPU
/0/a                        memory      3GiB System Memory
/0/a/0                      memory      1GiB SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
/0/a/1                      memory      2GiB SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
/0/100                      bridge      Mobile 945GSE Express Memory Controller Hub
/0/100/2                    display     Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/2.1                  display     Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
/0/100/1b                   multimedia  NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                   bridge      NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1
/0/100/1c.1                 bridge      NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2
/0/100/1c.1/0   wlan0       network     PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
/0/100/1d                   bus         NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
/0/100/1d.7                 bus         NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
/0/100/1e                   bridge      82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
/0/100/1e/6                 bridge      CB1410 Cardbus Controller
/0/100/1e/8     eth0        network     82562ET/EZ/GT/GZ - PRO/100 VE (LOM) Ethernet Controller Mobile
/0/100/1f                   bridge      82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge
/0/100/1f.2                 storage     82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/1            scsi0       storage     
/0/1/0.0.0      /dev/sda    disk        500GB TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0
/0/1/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1   volume      55GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2   volume      410GiB Extended partition
/0/1/0.0.0/2/5  /dev/sda5   volume      195GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/1/0.0.0/2/6  /dev/sda6   volume      172GiB HPFS/NTFS partition
/0/1/0.0.0/2/7  /dev/sda7   volume      3060MiB Linux swap / Solaris partition
/0/1/0.0.0/2/8  /dev/sda8   volume      39GiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/2            scsi1       storage     
/0/2/0.0.0      /dev/cdrom  disk        DVDRAM GSA-T20N
Linux prasanna 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
[    0.000000] DMI: Hewlett-Packard HP 520 Notebook PC/30D5, BIOS 68MVU Ver. F.07 03/18/2008
[    0.000000] Found optimal setting for mtrr clean up
[    0.124777] ACPI: No dock devices found.
[    0.125240] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    0.125278] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    0.160686] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    0.166459] Found 1 acpi root devices
[    0.166601] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.166601] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.166601] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.170087] Switched to clocksource hpet
[    0.179321] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices
[    0.218302] pci 0000:02:08.0: Firmware left e100 interrupts enabled; disabling
[    0.668099] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[    0.696460] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
[    0.696494] ACPI: Lid Switch [C20C]
[    0.808119] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.808122] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.808125] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.808128] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-32-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.808130] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.7
[    0.808257] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.808932] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    0.808935] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.808938] usb usb2: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    0.808940] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-32-generic uhci_hcd
[    0.808943] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    0.809057] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.817703] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: a7fc6590fc4a8d859aaebda2ca5dd04716244fa0'
[    0.885012] IMA: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    0.886064] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    1.097279] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[    1.120094] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.261678] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=330d
[    1.261683] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.261686] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[    1.261689] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    1.261691] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[    1.264957] e100 0000:02:08.0 eth0: addr 0xf0101000, irq 20, MAC addr 00:1e:ec:a1:d5:f0
[    9.280791] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    9.595991] [Firmware Bug]: _BCQ is used instead of _BQC
[    9.596042] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    9.606285] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    9.669604] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    9.676143] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    9.781350] iwl3945: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG/BG Network Connection driver for Linux, in-tree:s
[    9.781356] iwl3945: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[    9.787063] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    9.853481] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Tunable channels: 11 802.11bg, 13 802.11a channels
[    9.853487] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Detected Intel Wireless WiFi Link 3945ABG
[    9.853563] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[    9.863209] yenta_cardbus 0000:02:06.0: CardBus bridge found [103c:30d5]
[    9.877750] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-3945-rs'
[    9.971759] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   10.436116] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x50
[   10.440962] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   10.448407] leds_ss4200: no LED devices found
[   10.844713] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   10.844720] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   10.844722] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   10.844725] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   10.844727] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   10.844729] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   10.844731] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   10.901287] EXT4-fs (sda8): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   14.606592] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   14.626272] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   14.627509] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   15.248165] type=1400 audit(1418673050.858:48): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-ofono" pid=745 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.248956] type=1400 audit(1418673050.858:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-ofono" pid=745 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.249291] type=1400 audit(1418673050.858:51): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-ofono" pid=745 comm="apparmor_parser"
    Release Date: 03/18/2008
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP 520 Notebook PC
    Serial Number: CND8374QLD
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: 30D5
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Serial Number: CND8374QLD
    Manufacturer: Intel(R)
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Manufacturer: CE00000000000000
    Serial Number: 303EDB82
    Manufacturer: 7F98000000000000
    Serial Number: 7A15580F
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop
blacklist ath_pci
blacklist eth1394
# replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54
# replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist acer-wmi
blacklist uart6850
blacklist twl4030_wdt
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
sudo: hwinfo: command not found
root       669  0.0  0.3  54488 10208 ?        Ssl  01:20   0:00 NetworkManager
prasanna  2277  0.0  0.0   4432   768 pts/2    S+   01:26   0:00 egrep --color=auto wpa|icd|etwork
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
total 28428
2097153 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Dec  8 06:23 .
      2 drwxr-xr-x 22 root root     4096 Dec  8 06:21 ..
2097156 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  1166929 Jul 15 10:36 abi-3.13.0-32-generic
2097157 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   169732 Jul 15 10:36 config-3.13.0-32-generic
2097154 drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Dec  8 06:22 grub
2097173 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 18701723 Dec  8 06:23 initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
2097158 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   176500 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.bin
2097159 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   178176 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+.elf
2097160 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   178680 Mar 12  2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
2097155 -rw-------  1 root root  2693057 Jul 15 10:36 System.map-3.13.0-32-generic
2109674 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  5820336 Jul 23 03:54 vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
Support status summary of 'prasanna':


You have 1693 packages (100.0%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 0 packages (0.0%) that are unsupported

Run with --show-unsupported, --show-supported or --show-all to see more details
--2014-12-16 01:26:28--  http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids
Resolving www.linux-usb.org (www.linux-usb.org)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘www.linux-usb.org’
update-usbids: download failed
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   18895  2 
rfcomm                 53664  0 
bluetooth             342206  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_conexant    47785  1 
hp_wmi                 13702  0 
sparse_keymap          13708  1 hp_wmi
pcmcia                 51828  0 
parport_pc             31981  0 
coretemp               13195  0 
ppdev                  17391  0 
rtl8192cu              66675  0 
kvm                   388083  0 
snd_hda_intel          42730  2 
snd_hda_codec         164067  2 snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85501  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 17101  0 
arc4                   12536  2 
yenta_socket           40201  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            18319  1 yenta_socket
rtl_usb                18072  1 rtl8192cu
serio_raw              13230  0 
lpc_ich                16864  0 
pcmcia_core            22328  3 pcmcia,pcmcia_rsrc,yenta_socket
iwl3945                63619  0 
iwlegacy               88016  1 iwl3945
rtlwifi                52835  2 rtl_usb,rtl8192cu
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
rtl8192c_common        47340  1 rtl8192cu
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
mac80211              546051  5 iwl3945,iwlegacy,rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            25135  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
cfg80211              409394  4 iwl3945,iwlegacy,mac80211,rtlwifi
i915                  705659  3 
wmi                    18673  1 hp_wmi
drm_kms_helper         47182  1 i915
snd                    60871  14 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
video                  18903  1 i915
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
mac_hid                13037  0 
drm                   244037  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
soundcore              12600  1 snd
psmouse                91329  0 
e100                   35945  0 
mii                    13654  1 e100
```

thanks all

Comment: Ok, first of all, could you please move this mass of ugly text into a pastebin or something? It is very hard to understand what you are asking when there are pages of text.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to get the internal wireless working? It appears to be disabled by the hardware switch or key combination.

Comment: Hey sorry guys. i too felt that the text is really too big. but i just followed the instructions in the wireless trouble shooting guideline.

Answer (score 1):

you may read this [aticle](http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-11-16-d-link-dwa-131-n300-usb-wifi-adapter) and try:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu swenc=1
echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
```

Answer (score 1):

My D-link Wifi dongle has the following specs:

- D-Link Wireless N300 Nano USB Adapter
- Model number: DWA-131
- H/W version: E1
- F/W version: 5.00

Here is what I did, after being looking on the internet for a very long time:

1) Go to http://support.dlink.com.au/Download/download.aspx?product=DWA-131 and download the file "DWA-131 Linux driver v4.3.1.1.zip (5.88 MB)" in section "REV E" (at the top of the page). 
2) Move the file to a directory of your choice, extract it and change to the directory you've just extracted. This is (at the directory you chose):

- tar -zxvf 20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320.tar.gz
- cd 20140812_rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320/

3) Enter the following commands:

- make
- su (your password will be required)
- make install

You don't even  need to restart your computer. In my case, it worked instantly.

I hope you find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/archives_Division/12721_div_v1/12721_div.HTML

[image: HP 520 Notebook]

Have you tried pushing the button to the left of the power button to see if it enables wifi, it is #2 in the picture.  If it works as designed it should at least toggle the hard block in `rfkill list all`